# how to pass UITextField value in swift to .m file?

Tags: ios, swift

I have done with bridging , and i can send value from .m file to swift file and vice-versa.
My problem is that I am unable to send UITextField value from swift to .m.

my code is

Swift file

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var txt: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

     txt.text = "swift"

    //---- call property and method from  objective-C
    var instanceOfCustomObject: CustomObject = CustomObject()

    instanceOfCustomObject.someMethod()

    var propertyFromObjC: AnyObject! = instanceOfCustomObject.someProperty
    println("value from objective-C \(propertyFromObjC)")


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

and .m file is

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "CustomObject.h"

#import "Bridging-Swift.h"

@implementation CustomObject


- (void) someMethod {

    _someProperty=@"someProperty";

    NSLog(@"valueFromObjective-C method");
    ViewController *swiftObj = [ViewController new];
    NSLog(@"value from swift textfield %@", swiftObj.txt.text );
}

@end
```

result is : 
valueFromObjective-C method
**value from swift textfield (null)  --- this is my problem**
value from objective-C someProperty

Comment: Is this an academic experiment? Otherwise you have a massive design problem. If `someMethod` needs a property from the caller you add a parameter to the method of the callee. You don't pull in instances from all over the place to get that property.

Comment: Thanks..so what should I do to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new object of ViewController class in line

```
ViewController *swiftObj = [ViewController new];
```

This will be a new object and not the one you want to access. This is the reason it gives you a nil.

You may have to pass instance of ViewController to your CustomObject via init or some other way in order to access it in your somemethod().

```
@implementation CustomObject

- (id) initWithViewController:(ViewController*) vc {
    self.vc = vc
}

- (void) someMethod {

    _someProperty=@"someProperty";

    NSLog(@"valueFromObjective-C method");

    NSLog(@"value from swift textfield %@", self.vc.txt.text );
}
@end
```

Swift Side:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()

 txt.text = "swift"

 //---- call property and method from  objective-C
 var instanceOfCustomObject: CustomObject = CustomObject(self)

 instanceOfCustomObject.someMethod()

 var propertyFromObjC: AnyObject! = instanceOfCustomObject.someProperty
 println("value from objective-C \(propertyFromObjC)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. i am facing same problem if I create object like ViewController *swiftObj = [[ViewController alloc]init];  can u suggest some example or solution on it?